# PaperTrail whodunnit set to name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, paper-trail-gem

how to set whodunnit to current_user name.

Currently i use of whodunnit id to find the name of particular MODEL

```
versions.each do |a|
 
  = MODEL.find(a.whodunnit).name

end
```

here's the problem what if the MODEL that we finding is DELETED. im getting a error

so my GOAL is to save the current_user name in whodunnit. is this possible?

Comment: PaperTrail documents many ways to set whodunnit. https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#4a-finding-out-who-was-responsible-for-a-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_paper_trail_whodunnit

  protected
  
  def user_for_paper_trail
    current_user&.name || "Public User"
  end
end
```

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: I am glad to help you out. Thanks. :)